# Tasks limit amount threads

Tags: c#, task

I am developing a tcp server that processes commands.
When command arrives a use Task.Run to handle processing on a different thread to unblock the requesting side. The problem is that it is possible for requesting side to make large amount of request thus causing processing side to create lots of threads which subsequently based on my observation can cripple it and unable to process new requests.

Essentially what i need that a single requesting side can have defined max of requests processed and all of other requests queued for later execution.

So my question is should i be looking at a custom Task Scheduler ?
There is an Microsoft example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.100).aspx

I haven't started digging deeper as i wanted to see that this is the actual road i would need to go.

Comment: How about just having the regular async sockets, then when a request comes run that async and when it's done resume receiving data from the client? That way a single client can have one request going on. In any case I'd limit it on that side, not going for custom schedulers or anything.

Comment: ThreadPool will handle "throttling" for you.

Comment: Maybe you can limit the number of thread with SemaphoreSlim .
SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10)

Comment: @Jérôme This could work but essentially but i think with a scheduler i could have a better control of pending task. e.g if requesting side disconnects i could deque any outstanding task that have not been yet started.